# Umlauts and special characters preservation (Send-MailMessage)

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

I am having a problem with the formatting of an e-mail. I have special characters in the body and they are not being displayed correctly, I have tried several solutions but the e-mail keeps arriving with a format that does not interpret special characters. The body of the e-mail has to be sent in plain text, so I cannot use **[-BodyAsHtml]**. Here is my function. I hope someone can help me. Best regards

```
function SendMail {
    $PDFName = $settings.pdf.Name
    $WebResponseObj = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $PDFUrl
    $getLastModified = $WebResponseObj.Headers.'Last-Modified'
    $PDFdate = [DateTime]$getLastModified
    $dateTimePDF = $PDFdate.DateTime
    $plainTextBody = "
    Meldung über das aktualisierte Dokument `r`n
    File Name: $PDFName `r`n
    File Url: $PDFUrl `r`n
    Letzte Aktualisierung: $dateTimePDF `r`n
    Letzte Aktualisierungsprüfung: $getDateTime
    "
    $param = @{ 
        SmtpServer = $settings.mail.SmtpServer
        Port = $settings.mail.Port
        UseSsl = $true
        Credential = $userCredential
        From = $settings.mail.FromUser
        To = $settings.mail.ToUser
        Subject = $settings.mail.Subject
        Body = $plainTextBody
        Priority = 'High'
        DeliveryNotificationOption = 'OnFailure'
        ErrorAction = 'Stop'
        Encoding = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    }
    Send-MailMessage @param
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, the .ps1 file was in **UTF-8** format and to be interpreted correctly it has to be **UTF-8 with BOM**, that's it!

Comment: If you are using VSCode, you can add this in the settings.json file so all new files you create are automatically created using the desired encoding (eg: `"files.encoding": "utf8bom",`). This will help not getting into that issue here and there in the future.
(Note, it doesn't change existing file encoding though so it wouldn't have solved your issue but might help prevent some instances of it in the future)

Comment: @SagePourpre Thank you for your answer, this is what I have done in my VSCode configuration.